# How to merge cells in datagridview with equal values and draw line in a cell

Tags: vb.net

This is my dataGridview Result:

[image]

and what I expect:

[image]

I want to merge cells in first column that are equal. I'm using this code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView2_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellPainting

    If e.RowIndex = 0 Then

        If (DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString()) Then
            If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
                DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0).Value = ""
                e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
            End If
        End If

    End If

    If e.RowIndex > 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex < DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2 Then
            If (DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex - 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString()) Then
                If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
                    DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = ""
                    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                End If
            End If

            If (DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString()) Then
                If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
                    DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0).Value = ""
                    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

It works but when I select a row, becomes corrupted. Also I would like to separate my data for each group by a red line. In addition draw a diagonal in top cell and write the names.

Comment: What do you mean 'becomes corrupted'?

Comment: I mean it becomes like first photo.